# Why is the output junk value

Tags: c, for-loop, multidimensional-array, undefined-behavior, function-definition

In the below code, When I did the same logic without using functions it gave correct answer.
But with using functions its giving some junk value. The question was to print the sum of diagonal matrix in array using c using functions.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int read(int a[][100],int,int);
int displayres(int a[][100],int,int);
int main()
{
    int m,n,a[100][100];
    printf("Enter the number of rows: ");
    scanf("%d",&m);
    printf("Enter the number of columns: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    if(m==n)
        read(a,m,n);
    displayres(a,m,n);
}


int read(int a[][100],int m,int n)
{
    int i,j;
    if(m==n)
    printf("Enter the elements:\n");
    for(i=0;i<m;i++)
    {    
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            scanf("%d",&a[i][j]);
        }
    }
    
}



int displayres(int a[][100],int m,int n)
{
    int i,j,abc;
    
        for(i=0,j=0;i<m,j<n;i++,j++)
        {
            abc = abc + a[i][j];
        }
    printf("%d\n",abc);  
        
}
```

Comment: No bro this works in the main function without using user-defined if i give row size column size

Comment: `abc` is uninitialized.

Comment: What is the correct answer? For which input? What do you get instead? How did the working code look like? Please provide a [mre] of both versions.

Comment: Possibly unrelated: your functions are missing a `return` statement... or maybe being defined as `void`.

Comment: Got it bro Thank you! abc was not initialized.

Comment: You only assign any values to the array when `(m==n)` There does not seem to be any point entering two separate values.

Comment: `for(i=0,j=0;i<m,j<n;i++,j++)` <<-- funny loop (lookup the comma operator)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As the diagonal is processed for quadratic matrices then these declarations of the functions

```
int read(int a[][100],int,int);
int displayres(int a[][100],int,int);
```

do not make a great sense. One parameter is redundant. The functions can be declared like

```
void read(int a[][100], size_t );
int displayres(int a[][100], size_t );
```

correspondingly instead of these two prompts

```
printf("Enter the number of rows: ");
scanf("%d",&m);
printf("Enter the number of columns: ");
scanf("%d",&n);
```

you should use only one prompt and also you need to check that the entered number (for example n) is not greater than 100.

As the function `read` returns nothing its return type should be `void`.

Its definition can look like

```
void read(int a[][100], size_t n )
{
    printf("Enter the elements:\n");
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {    
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < n; j++ )
        {
            scanf("%d",&a[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Within the function `displayres` you forgot to initialize the variable `abc`. And the function should not output anything. It should return the calculated value. The function can look the following way

```
int displayres(int a[][100], size_t n )
{
    int abc = 0;
    
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        abc += a[i][i];
    }

    return abc;        
}
```

And in main you can write

```
printf( "The sum is %d\n", displayres( a, n ) );
```

If you want to calculate the sum for a matrix of any sizes then the function `displayres` can look the following way

```
int displayres( int a[][100], size_t m, size_t n )
{
    int abc = 0;
    
    for ( size_t; i < m && i < n; i++ )
    {
        abc += a[i][i];
    }

    return abc;        
}
```

As for your for loop then you are using the comma operator in the condition

```
    for(i=0,j=0;i<m,j<n;i++,j++)
```

It is the same as to write

```
    for( i=0, j=0; j < n; i++,j++ )
```

because the value of the first operand of the comma operator is discarded.